# Modify Tensorflow model at runtime

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to modify data flow of a tensorflow model at runtime. Consider a 3 layers FC neural network. Let's say I want to define 2 different layers for the middle position.

Let's say,
1st option: 64 neuron layer
2nd option: 128 neuran layer.

Then during predict function, I want to give an input alongside the input data like;

```
model.predict([x_test, decider])
```

Then if decider is 0, I want my model to execute 64 neuron layer as middle layer. Otherwise, I want my model to execute 128 neuron layer as middle layer.

If I choose one of them, I don't want the other option to be executed for performance reasons.

Note: I do not care for training.

Is there a way to do that? So far, I have been trying to use tf.cond() but could not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve same thing by recombine the independent models:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import numpy as np

# First model
input_shape = (16, )
inputs_0 = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
outputs_0 = layers.Dense(256, 'relu')(inputs_0)
fc_0 = models.Model(inputs_0, outputs_0)
# Middel model 0
inputs_1_0 = layers.Input(shape=(256, ))
outputs_1_0 = layers.Dense(64, 'relu')(inputs_1_0)
outputs_1_0 = layers.Dense(128, 'relu')(outputs_1_0)
fc_1_0 = models.Model(inputs_1_0, outputs_1_0)
# Middel model 1
inputs_1_1 = layers.Input(shape=(256, ))
outputs_1_1 = layers.Dense(128, 'relu')(inputs_1_1)
outputs_1_1 = layers.Dense(128, 'relu')(outputs_1_1)
fc_1_1 = models.Model(inputs_1_1, outputs_1_1)
# Last model
inputs_2 = layers.Input(shape=(128, ))
outputs_2 = layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')(inputs_2)
fc_2 = models.Model(inputs_2, outputs_2)

def custom_model(x, d):
    h = fc_0(x)
    if d == 1:
        h = fc_1_0(h)
    else:
        h = fc_1_1(h)
    return fc_2(h)

x = np.random.rand(1, input_shape[0])
decider = 0 # Middel model 0 or 1
y = custom_model(x, decider)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I can certainly do that. But, This will require lots of memory while the number of combinations increases. I will require 100s of combinations for my project. Therefore, I wanted to modify the existing model so that I will not exceed the RAM's capacity.

Comment: Glad to help, I think the memory needs is mainly depend on the number of layer you define (number of parameters) and batch of data you feed in, not by number of combinations you have or the way you combine it, if you really have problem on memory usage about you just claimed, then please make another problem, I'll take a look.

Comment: But if you want, you could always dynamically define the model at runtime when you need it, that should increase memory usage model by model

Comment: My intention was to update the tensorflow graph so that I do not need to save layer weights from all combinations.But it turns out that tf graph cannot be modified after it is built. In this case, I wanted to go with your solution.But your solution has a performance degredation. In other words, If I define two different complete models (one is using your middle model 0, other is using middle model 1),they outperform your custom model here. I think the reason is that when each mini model finishes, they copy the results back to the CPU. Then it is copied back to GPU for next mini model.Any Idea?

Comment: Also, I cannot define models on the run (dynamically). Because, I need to change models between two inference, without waiting at all if possible.